# To set data in attribute "VALUE" using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a use case where I need to set VALUE for a input tag.

'''

```
module.exports = async function(selectorId, inputString) {
    const randomDate = inputString;
    console.log(rdate)

    await this.page.evaluate(((el) => {el.value = ""}), selector[0]);
    await this.page.evaluate(((el,randomDate ) => {el.value = randomDate },randomDate ), selectorId[0]);
    await this.page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    
    };
```

'''

Here this code is working fine but it is not doing any action on UI, like not setting the selectorId.value as per definition, I am using xPath for the object. Can any one help on same.

Comment: Could you show the DOM or URL you're working with, please, along with a runnable Puppeteer snippet so I can easily reproduce the problem? The second `evaluate`'s parentheses look funny, though. You may have meant `this.page.evaluate((el, randomDate) => {el.value = randomDate;}, selectorId[0], randomDate);`.

Comment: Also in the first evaluate you are using `selector[0]` and in the second you are using `selectorID[0]`.  You probably intended those to be consistent.